# 変数を使わずに数値を１上げたい

Tags: c#, winforms

`pictureBox1`をクリックすると[1]を[2]にしたいです。
変数無しでやるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
グローバル変数などは使いたくありません。
配列.nextみたいなのを探しています。
なるべく１行でやりたいです。

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Directory.GetFiles(label1.Text, "*.*")[1];
}
```

Comment: おそらく要件を満たすのは無理。

Comment: `.next()` で順番に辿れるということは、「現在の要素」や「残りの要素」といった状態をどこかに持つことになります。例えば PHP の配列は配列自身がそのような状態を持っているので `next()` `current()` といった関数がありますが、C# ではそのような状態と操作を `GetEnumerator()` で取得できるオブジェクトに分離しています。それを保持して使うのがpulserさんの方法ですね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ローカル変数でIEnumeratorを１個だけ持ってもよければ可能ですが

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<string> ie = null;
            label1.Click += (s, e) => { var d = new FolderBrowserDialog(); if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) label1.Text = d.SelectedPath; };
            label1.TextChanged += (s, e) => { ie = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(label1.Text, "*.*").Cast<string>().GetEnumerator(); };
            pictureBox1.Click += (s, e) => { pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ie == null ? null : ie.MoveNext() ? ie.Current : null; };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法は使いませんが、今後役に立ちそうです。

Answer (score 3):

もし、RX(nugetでRx-Mainを追加してください)が使える環境ならばローカル変数なくても可能かと思います。
お決まりのusing句は省略します。適宜追加してください

```
using System.Reactive.Linq; //これを追加
class Form1:Form
{
    Form1()
    {
        Observable
            .FromEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>(h => (sender, e) => h(e), h => pictureBox1.Click += h, h => pictureBox1.Click -= h)
            .Select((e, index) => new { e, index })
            .Subscribe(v => pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Directory.GetFiles(label1.Text, "*.*")[v.index]);

    }
}
```

数値のリセットとか考慮する点はまだありますが、質問の内容は満たせると思います。
　※indexは0から始まるので適宜使用すればよいです。